# Cross-browser link to file on local system

Tags: html, cross-browser, file-link

I would like to make a link from a web page to a file on a local filesystem and make it work in all browsers (or at least in Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome).

For example, the following works in Internet Explorer:

```
<a href="\\myserver\doc\info.pdf">Info here</a>
```

but not in Firefox and Chrome.

Is there a way to make a link that works in all browsers?

Or a way to use javascript to detect which browser it is and then display the appropriate link based on the filename?

Comment: Not that this is pure conjecture, but files "downloaded" from the local file system from a network share typically have different security attributes than ones downloaded from a web server. This might thus be seen as a way to circumvent security, and might very well not be allowed at all in other browsers.

Comment: Similar question on SuperUser with more details: [How do I instruct Firefox to allow me to open file:/// URLs on a localhost-server http:// webpage?](https://superuser.com/questions/1513156/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Links to local files on pages that were retrieved via HTTP(S) are deliberately disabled in Mozilla/Firefox, because they can be a security risk, and have been used in attacks in the past.

You can override this behaviour, however. For details, see [this article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Issues_:_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work) in MozillaZine.

Comment: Very old but anyway, since I've got an issue with this: why is this a security issue? why is it more a problem compare to download the same file via HTTP?

Comment: @Rafiki: The linked article lists some risks. If you want to know more, this sounds like an excellent new question. Consider asking it as such on https://security.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 9):

try prefixing your url with file:///

Comment: You'll also need to convert the back slashes to forward slashes, thus your example would be file://///myserver/doc/info.pdf. This is covered in the link sleske gave in his answer.