# HTML links to local network shares

Tags: html, hyperlink, network-share

Why do these links not work? If I click on them in FF or Chrome, nothing happens - it doesn't even *try* to open them!

```
<a href="file://someshare/dir/subdir/file.txt">Linky</a>
<a href="file:////someshare/dir/subdir/file.txt"> Linky</a>
<a href="file://\\someshare\dir\subdir\file.txt">Linky</a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: file:// protocol doesn't seem to work on FF

Comment: @Mauris: the file protocol works just fine on FF, just not for links from pages served over HTTP.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In general, this is disabled because it is a security risk. See also this question:
[Cross-browser link to file on local system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254572/cross-browser-link-to-file-on-local-system), and the link provided by sleske to [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox%5F:%5FIssues%5F:%5FLinks%5Fto%5FLocal%5FPages%5FDon%27t%5FWork).

Comment: The link provided by sleske is gone. @Sean O has an answer below

Answer (score 4):

This is an oldie, but goodie -- still comes up quite often.

There are extensions for both browsers (FireFox & Chrome) that can allow you to access local links:

**Chrome** - [Locallink](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida)

**Firefox** - [LocalLink](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/locallink/)

Comment: This works. :) is there any other way that I can convert the NFS path to a HTTP link??

Comment: Both links are broken.

Comment: That's ironic. :)

Answer (score 0):

Peter's got the answer, but FYI you should find something like the following in FF's Error Console (available from the Tools menu):

> Security Error: Content at http://localhost/temp/a.html may not load or link to file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/zzzzzzzz/My%20Documents/www/temp/box.html.