# chrome and firefox browser fails to launch windows folder from link

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, directory

I have a link that directs to a windows folder by its directory link. It works for internet explorer, but it doesn't work for chrome or firefox. How do i fix this?

my link goes something like this

```
<a href="\\directory\folder1\folder2">Click Here</a>
```

It works in internet explorer but it doesnt work for chrome? and it doesn't work in firefox either?

Comment: It is my understanding that, since they are not basically shell-integrated into windows, they wouldn't launch such a link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML links to local network shares](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465010/html-links-to-local-network-shares)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't be surprised if Chrome, being as sandboxed as it is, lacks the permissions to launch an external program. I don't use Firefox, but it wouldn't shock me at all if it was designed the same way.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<a href="file:///c:/directory/folder1/folder2" target="_new" >Click here</a>
```

also is this only being used by you because the chances of us both having the same folder structure is slim to none.

Comment: i tried doing this, but it doesn't work for mozilla or chrome, when i hover over the link it shows it but it doesn't do anything. This is only for local network

Answer (score 1):

As much as I know, MSIE is tightly connected with the windows explorer, so when you click a link to the folder, it goes to that folder. Also, when you type a link in the explorer window, it automatically redirects you to the required site by using MSIE.
While in Mozilla Firefox you need to specify that this is a local folder. As much as I know, you have to use the "file:///" prefix for that

Comment: Speaking about Mozilla, I found this page: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don%27t_work. There it says that local file access is blocked due to security problems, but you can work around by using the "locallink" extension