# Link to document on LAN from web page

Tags: html, hyperlink

I need to link to a file on a Windows file share from a web page.

I have tried using this path:

```
//B-1152151154/shared/file.txt
```

...but it says permission denied.

Is it possible to do so, same like accessing a local drive file (C:/shared/file.txt)

Comment: Does the user ID that PHP is running under have the appropriate permissions on the share **AND** the underlying directory? Rights have to be granted on BOTH for this to work.

Comment: "Permission denied" probably means the file was found, so I guess yes, it is possible, otherwise you would have got "No such file or directory"

Comment: Using windows, able to access the folder directly through: //B-1152151154/shared (in windows explorer)

Comment: Also, I found out that you can't trigger this in FF, it's an IE only thing. Something about FF putting a restriction on a web site opening explorer. Although if you prove me wrong, I will be very happy :)

Comment: That doesnt mean the php process can access it. A process can run in a different security-level then you.

Comment: @KevinCollins able to access in FF too using file://///B-1152151154/shared/file.txt

Comment: Are you trying to access a file on the server or the client?

Comment: @Akash, then this has **absolutely nothing** to do with PHP.

Comment: php scripts run essentailly as guest unless configured otherwise. To access a share on another computer (a server), the script needs to be authenticated in some way on that other server. It sounds like you are computer (1), running script on computer (2), which you want to access computer (3).

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML links to local network shares](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465010/html-links-to-local-network-shares)