# Wordpress, open folder on server in company network by link or button

Tags: wordpress, ftp, external-links

Is it possible to create a link on a wordpresspage to allow access for all my employees to a location on our network? I don't want to upload alle the documents because they are updated by some people.

I have a Wordpress intranet page and want to link to this folder on our server:

I can access over browser with file:///M:/Data/ or direkt from my pc

But if i try to access over a link like

```
<a href="file:///M:/Data">Link </>
```

in wordpress nothing happens or i got blocked from browser. I also tried //, ///, ///// e.g...all what i have found in web.

I want that all members can download or view these files (by browser or windows explorer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers treat this (linking from http/https to local files) as a security threat, so it is not possible without a workaround. There are browser extensions available that bypass this block. See this thread for explanations and links to browser extensions:
[HTML links to local network shares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465010/html-links-to-local-network-shares)

Comment: so its only possible to upload all needed files?

Comment: Hi Eric. You can bypass the block if everyone installs a browser extension specific to this (see above link). Or you can upload all files in WordPress. But as you mention yourself you "don't want to upload all the documents because they are updated by some people". These, however, are your two choices (there are other ways but very difficult to code and for which I am not the right person to ask).