# Redirection to a locale page with a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I'd like to have a page redirecting to another using Javascript. I've tried with document.location.href but it doesn't work with local pages (stored in my hard drive).
 Does someone know something that would do the trick ?

thanks,

Bruno

Comment: Try `window.location` instead. `document.location` is read-only.

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254572/cross-browser-link-to-file-on-local-system and this one for IE: http://superuser.com/questions/266908/why-doesnt-a-link-to-a-local-word-document-work-in-internet-explorer bottom line - not possible due to security reasons.

Comment: I think it's a security measure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this on the xul file of the extension :

```
function Read(file)
{
 var ioService=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
     .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
 var scriptableStream=Components
     .classes["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"]
     .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableInputStream);

 var channel=ioService.newChannel(file,null,null);
 var input=channel.open();
 scriptableStream.init(input);
 var str=scriptableStream.read(input.available());
 scriptableStream.close();
 input.close();
 return str;
}

gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
   var documentElement = e.originalTarget.defaultView.document;
   var div = documentElement.createElement("div");
   div.innerHTML = Read("chrome://firefox_extension/content/locale.html");
   documentElement.body.appendChild(div);
},

false

);
```

the complete extension : http://uploadingit.com/file/xef7llflgmjgfzin/my_firefox_extension.xpi

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it? I've tried the following and it works fine:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" value="" id="test"/>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.location.href = "file:///C:/dev/PICCS/vb/binaries/";
   </script>
</html>
```

Tested in IE8 and Chrome

Comment: I've tried your trick : the files does open but there is nothing inside

Comment: No Google Chrome and my file is inside the www folder in wamp.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - Yes, although the only version I have access to is 3.0.5