# Displaying a pdf on a network share via a link

Tags: html, networking, web

I am trying to display a pdf via a link but I can't figure out how to address it.  I can display the image in both ie and firefox with this:

\\192.168.nn.nn\sharedfolder\folder\200211ACD\AX2F0345\0247.PDF

But when I code this:

```
<a href="\\192.168.nn.nn\sharedfolder\folder\200211ACD\AX2F0345\0431.PDF">SS9230</a>
```

I get this in my address bar:

```
localhost/\\192.168.nn.nnn\sharedfolder\folder\200211ACD\AX2F0345\0429.PDF
```

But when I copied it to paste it here it looked like this:

```
http://localhost\\192.168.nn.nn\sharedfolder\folder\200211ACD\AX2F0345\0429.PDF
```

I tried prefixing it with "http:" but this did not work either.  I have a local copy of wamp installed and do not know if this is interferring in any way.  I had someone else try and they can get a directory listing by entering " \\192.168.nn.nn\sharedfolder".  I just want a page with links to images on a share to be able to display them.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML, it looks like you are referencing through the file system instead of an absolute path. You should refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254572/cross-browser-link-to-file-on-local-system) and/or try using:

```
<a href="http://192.168.nn.nn/sharedfolder/folder/200211ACD/AX2F0345/0431.PDF">SS9230</a>
```

Comment: I tried that.  It didn't work.  Also that article doesn't provide any additional information either, thanks anyway.

Comment: It does.UNC Paths If you're linking to a file in a UNC path (e.g., \\servername\share\file.ext), you will need to specify the path thusly:
file://///servername/share/file.ext
Also note that you cannot link to file://///servername to get a listing of shares at that hostname due to a bug.
It also says it is disable in most cases for security reasons.  My example wouldn't work unless you have it at least in the root folder of your website, so maybe I should have put:<a href="http://192.168.nn.nn/wwwroot/sharedfolder/folder/200211ACD/AX2F0345/0431.PDF">SS9230</a>